# Setting default value of the property with PropertyBuilder and SetConstant

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, reflection.emit

I have pretty simple piece of code

```
var propertyBuilder =
    typeBuilder.DefineProperty(upperName, PropertyAttributes.None, propertyType, new[] { propertyType });
propertyBuilder.SetConstant(Convert.ChangeType(propertyInfo.Default, propertyType));
```

After that when I call `CreateType()` method and create an instance of the class I am trying to inspect value of the property with the default value assigned, but I cannot see any changes.

I cannot use `SetValue` method after I create an instance of the class, because all constructed types are stored inside metadata dictionary and can be used from different places in the code.

Any suggestions why `SetConstant` method is not working?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use `SetValue()`. `SetValue()` affects only one instance of the type, it wouldn't affect “different places in the code” (unless they shared the same instance of the type).

Comment: Also, do you really want to create indexer (i.e. property with parameters) and not a normal property? Because that's what setting `parameterTypes` does.

Comment: I need to affect All instances of the type, that's why I want to use SetConstant method while building the type

Comment: I changed the last parameter to null, but it's still the same behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetConstant()` doesn't do what you think it does. It sets a “default value” associated with the property, but that value is not actually used anywhere (though you can retrieve it using [`GetConstantValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getconstantvalue.aspx)).

To actually return some constant value from the getter of the property, you will need to create the getter method and set its IL to return the value. But since you can't store arbitrary types in the assembly itself, this will be hard to do generically. For example, if the property was `int`, it would look like this:

```
var getMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
    "get_" + upperName, MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);

var il = getMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, defaultValue);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(
    upperName, PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(int), Type.EmptyTypes);
propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getMethodBuilder);
```

`ldc.i4` is an IL instruction to load a constant integer onto the IL stack. For other types, you would need different instructions.

Comment: Cool, but in that case what is the most common usage of SetConstant method?

Comment: Also I need to return default value only for the first time, when the instance is created. After that the user can modify the value of the property

Comment: I have never seen any usages of `SetConstant()`, I have no idea what is it used for. And if you want more complicated behavior, you will need more complicated IL. In your case, you probably want to create a backing field and set that to the default value.